# Match Path using Regex in Java

Tags: java, regex, path, string-matching, regex-greedy

I'm trying to match the pattern path which follows:
`secret/roles/[can be anything]/dev/[Variable]/[can be additional child paths or just empty]`

I tried the following:

```
String Vairable = "john";
String RegularExpression = "(secret/roles)?(/[a-zA-Z0-9_.-])?(/dev)?(/" + Variable + ")?(/[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)+/?";
```

but it doesn't filter the `Variable` part and basically captures all the child paths under `secret/roles/...`

Comment: Try `String RegularExpression = "secret/roles/[^/]+/dev/"+Vairable+"/.*";`. Note you define a `Vairable` and then use `Variable`. Do you use `find()` or `matches()`? Please add the whole relevant code and explain what output you get and what output you need.

Comment: I'd suggest ditching regex (at least for evaluating the whole path) and using the Java (8+) Path API. You can e.g. evaluate the path element before last that way.

Comment: Segue: and if your rules are more complex (optional path elements, path elements depending on previous path elements) you can always evaluate each element in its sequence order and draw conclusions.

Comment: Here, `[can be anything]` can only have one character.

Comment: Why all the `?` question marks?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you for the suggestion, it worked. could you also tell me if it is possible that we could also cover `secret/roles/[Anything]/dev/[Variable]` ? as in no child paths after `Variable`? I use `matches()` by the way.

Comment: @user16320675 no I mean there can be

Comment: yes that's right, any suggestions?

Comment: `Can be anything` means one or more chars other than `/` (`[^/]+`), since the subpart cannot be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `matches`, you can use either

```java
String RegularExpression = "secret/roles/[^/]+/dev/"+Pattern.quote(Vairable)+"/.*";
```

Or

```java
String RegularExpression = "secret/roles/[^/]+/dev/"+Pattern.quote(Vairable)+"/[^/]*";
```

In the first case, anything can go after `Vairable` and a backslash, in the latter, only one subpart is allowed, no `/` chars can appear after that backslash.

The `Pattern.quote()` is added to escape any special regex metacharacters that may occur in the `Vairable` variable.

Comment: as I understand, from actual comment, the last slash is optional or only needed if there is something after `variable` and that slash

Comment: Yes, I would rather use `Pattern.quote(Vairable)`